# Issues with truncating an Oracle table on a daily basis

Tags: oracle, ddl, truncate, dml

Assume there is a staging table, which has some indexes, constraints defined on it. A process is dumping data into this table on a daily basis. A few million rows per day. Another process is taking data from the table on daily basis as well.
Once read, that days data is not worth any more, so no point in keeping the data in the table.

Current solution is to truncate the table (as opposed to "delete from"  the table because it is going to take long time considering the indexes and constraints over it) and load the data on daily basis.

My question is, is there any technical issues in doing truncating a table on daily basis?

PS: Using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 3):

No, there is absolutely no issue in truncating the staging table. In fact it is a standard data warehousing practice to truncate the staging table once the data is processed. However, I would recommend the following.

- It is better to truncate the staging table in the beginning of the
  process (just before data is loaded in it from landing or source
  tables). This will give you flexibility to do any debugging or data analysis in case the program populates some bad or inconsistent data in the downstream processes.
- Truncate is a DDL operation and it will issue an implicit commit, so all the operations before the truncate table in the concerned session would be committed and you will not be in a position to roll it back.

Comment: why I asked this, we ran a PoC on MySQL doing the same, after few months of usage, ( daily trucate and insert) the table got corrupted, When I say corrupted, a few months down the line, we had to drop the table and re-create it. MySQL never allowed me to re-create the table saying the table is already there. Had to switch the engine to create the table again! Dont want this to happen in production Oracle server.

Comment: @Aczire you may want to check what happens in MySQL while truncating a table with uncommited changes or while an insert from other session is running. See may answer for Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Some care should be taken with the distinction between *staging* and *interface* table. Typical staging table is full under the control of the ETL process for example with this daily lifecycle:

- Truncate table
- Load data in the table
- Select data from table for further steps.

On the contrary if the table is populated by processes not controlled by the ETL jobs, I’d call it *interface* table.

If the data producing job is a batch running once a day on a fixed schedule, there is no difference to the previous case and the **periodic truncate is fine.**

Some case should be taken in case that the data producing job is running at unknown time and / or several times a day.

Truncate of a table containing not committed data fails with

```
SQL-Fehler: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

In such a case (that the data may be produced at unknown schedule) a better solution is to use partitioned table (e.g. with daily [interval partition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE) schema).

- The producer job writes the data in the current partition.
- After some retention time (x days) the consumer **DROP**s the old partition.

This isolates the producer and the consumer and also gives some history for debugging and / or restart the load etc.